# Not sure how to call and print ASCII art method

Tags: java, boolean, ascii, call

I want to print out an Ascii art picture from a different method. My code does not work however. Here it is:

```
String avatar = IBIO.inputString ("Now tell me. Are you a boy? Or are you a girl? ");


 if (avatar == "boy" || avatar == "Boy" || avatar == "b" || avatar == "B")
 { 
 System.out.print (Boy );
 }

public void Boy ()
{
 {
  System.out.println ("    /:''|    ");    
  System.out.println ("   |: 66|_   ");  
  System.out.println ("   C     _)  ");  
  System.out.println ("    \\ ._|      ");
  System.out.println ("     ) /       ");
  System.out.println ("   /`\\       ");
  System.out.println ("   || |Y|       ");      
  System.out.println ("   || |#|       ");     
  System.out.println ("   || |#|       ");  
  System.out.println ("   || |#|       ");  
  System.out.println ("   :| |=:       "); 
  System.out.println ("   ||_|,|      ");
  System.out.println ("   \\)))||     ");
  System.out.println ("|~~~`-`~~~|   ");
  System.out.println ("|         |    ");
  System.out.println ("|_________|    ");
  System.out.println ("|_________|    ");
  System.out.println ("    | ||       ");
  System.out.println ("    |_||__        ");
  System.out.println ("    (____))    ");
}
}
```

Also, if the user types in girl, I want to make another method and print out a girl ascii art picture.

Comment: It is not working because you are doing it incorrectly. You should call `Boy` method as follows: `Boy();`. No need of enclosing it into `System.out.print();`.

Comment: this fixed the error but the boy picture still is not getting printed out

Comment: never mind it works now

Comment: Your String comparison logic is wrong. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not doing the `String` comparison properly. You should be using `equals()` or `equalsIgnoreCase()` and not `==` to compare the Strings.

Secondly, You should call Boy method as follows: `Boy();`. No need of enclosing it into `System.out.print();`.

Here is the corrected code snippet:

```
if ("boy".equalsIgnoreCase(avatar) || "b".equalsIgnoreCase(avatar)) {
    Boy();
}
```

Note that I'm using `equalsIgnoreCase()` here instead of just `equals()` and hence you need not to do the comparisons for String such as `Boy`, `BOY` or `B` etc.

Comment: Yes, I realized that. Thanks.

Comment: I wish i could but I don't yet have 15 rep :P

Comment: @lkjhgfdsa4321 It only allows you to select 1 answer. You should select the best one.